# Domino function proof?

Tags: functions

My professor gave me this function and I believe I understand how it works, but I am not experienced enough in maths to write a quick proof for it. Can someone write a proof for my conjecture if it's right or explain to me why I am wrong in detail?

> Numbers are aligned as dots and are ordered just like in a domino face so if it is 6 they are aligned in two rows of three, if it is one hundred its aligned in two rows of 50 and if it is 51 we align them as usual with 25 in both columns and eliminate the remainder.
>
> Take any N number put it through the process described above then take one of the rows put it through the process described above again until you either arrive at one or a infinite sequence. Does the sequence always end in 1?

I am fairly certain the answer is yes, but I would like someone to confirm it and explain to me in detail why I'm right or wrong.

Comment: Can you see that the sequence is strictly decreasing, except for $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each stage you’re dividing the number by $2$ and throwing away the remainder, if there is one. If you write your numbers in binary (base two), you’re simply shifting the number one place to the right. I’ll use $n=100$ as an example.

$$\begin{array}{r|r}
\text{base ten}&\text{base two}\\ \hline
100&1100100\\
50&110010\\
25&11001\\
12&1100\\
6&110\\
3&11\\
1&1
\end{array}$$

Assuming that we write the numbers with no leading zeroes, the first (leftmost) digit of a positive integer in base two is always $1$, so we eventually end up with $1$.